# How do I find the header or first row of an imported CSV?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I want to assign the header row of a .csv file as the dataprovider of a drop down list. So far I can load the .csv with a url request and loader. I assign the datatype as text and trace the output of the loader.data which shows me everything in the csv.

```
       protected function appendFileUploadedHandler(event:AppendFileUploaded):void
        {   
            userCSVRequest = new URLRequest("foo.com/myFile.csv");
            userCSVLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
            userCSVLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, csvLoader_complete);
            userCSVLoader.load(userCSVRequest);
        }

        public function csvLoader_complete(event:Event):void{
            trace(userCSVLoader.data.toString());
        }
```

What I can't figure out is how to determine where the first row / header row ends. Should I just convert the csv to xml or is there something I can do that doesn't involve that extra step. Some of the csv files will be very large so I dont want to waste the loading time.

Comment: Hmm. Wouldn't the first row end with a newline? I might be missing something about your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that runs into this problem, the solution is pretty simple. Nothing I found through searching gave me exactly what I needed. I ended up using the .split method on userCSV.data (which is a string type) and assigning the value to an array.

```
//will truncate everything past the first new line char. hopefully this is your header.
var headerArray:Array = userCSV.split("\n",1);
```